# Is there a way to programmatically push to GitHub using an oauth token?

Tags: bash, git, github, oauth

I want to use a bash script to push to a "build repository" for my Symfony app, which can then be deployed directly to a server. I have the following so far:

```
#!/bin/bash    
cd ..    
rm -rf api-analyzer-build    
git clone https://$OAUTH_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic@github.com/patrickmustermann/api-analyzer-build.git    
cd www    
composer install    
rsync -avr --exclude='.git' --exclude='.env.local' --exclude='.gitignore' ./ ../api-analyzer-build  
cd ../api-analyzer-build
git add *
git commit -m "Update"
git config --global user.email "$EMAIL"
git config --global user.name "$USER_NAME"
# Now I want to commit changes to my private api-analyzer-build.git build repository
```

This script successfully clones my private build repository from GitHub, installs all PHP dependencies via composer and clones the fully fleshed-out app back to the build folder.

Now I'm stuck on the last step: Pushing to my private build repository programmatically. **Is there a one-liner I can use to push to the build repository, using my `OAUTH_TOKEN` value from within my bash script?** Something similar to how I'm currently cloning from the repository?

Comment: You mean like `git push`? Did you try it?

Comment: It works! It looks like I should always try what I think is going to fail before asking ServerFault :-) 

But I'm a little surprised that it works without any special arguments. I guess Git is just smart enough to remember that I recently used an oauth token for authentication? What a nice surprise!

Comment: Type `git remote -v` and I think that will explain it.

Comment: Indeed it did. Nice.